# How to set the size of a wxplot2d plot in a wxMaxima worksheet?

Tags: plot, symbolic-math, maxima

I'd like to set the size of a wxplot2d plot on a maxima worksheet to be smaller or larger than the default. How does one do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
wxplot2d(sin(x),[x,0,2*%pi]),wxplot_size=[1024,768];
```

Comment: looks like the axes font sizes are fixed. do you know how to rescale them?

Comment: Add gnuplot preamble, something like this: wxplot2d(sin(x),[x,0,2*%pi],[gnuplot_preamble, "set font 'Arial,12';"),wxplot_size=[1024,768];

Comment: Sorry, I mean `wxplot2d(sin(x),[x,0,2*%pi],[gnuplot_preamble, "set term pngcairo font 'Arial,12';"),wxplot_size=[1024,768];`